# Why does the radio button show up as selected in jQuery even when it is not?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a radio button group with choices a,b, and other.  If the user chooses "other", the user is allowed to enter their own value in a text field.  The HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="a" value="a"/><label for="a">a</label><div></div>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="b" value="b"/><label for="b">b</label><div></div>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="other" value="other"/><label for="other">other </label><input type="text" id="otherText"/<div></div>
```

I am learning jQuery and came upon a behavior that maybe someone here could shed light on.  The text field by default is disabled and only enabled when the user clicks "other".  I have a blur attached to this textfield.  My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input#otherText").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $("input:radio").click(function() {
        var choice = $(this).val();
        if(choice != "other") {
            $("input#otherText").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }else {
            $("input#otherText").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
     });

    $("input#otherText").blur(function() {
        // why is this true even when I select "a" or "b"?
        console.log("Is other checked?: " + $("input#other").is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

My question concerns this:

```
console.log("Is other checked?: " + $("input#other").is(":checked"));
```

Why does the above always print true even when I choose some other radio button like "a" or "b"?
The reason I am asking about is that I eventually want to validate whatever the user entered in the other text field but only if "other" is checked. But since this is always the case, I will be forced to evaluate even when the user selects some other choice in the radio button group. I guess it is unavoidable but is there a way to get around this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the check for `&& otherError`, it's not defined, and according to what you're trying to do, it doesn't need to be. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UZZny/

Your console is going to print that it is `true` every-time because that textbox is only enabled when that radio is checked, the blur event fires, then your choice will change.